# Select where in subquery from one row with CSV values

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a subquery where the value returned is a CSV list of values I want to use for the SELECT WHERE IN clause

```
SELECT *
FROM Facility.FacilityIO f
where f.FacilityID in (
  select Facilities
  from FacilityListView
  where FacilityID = 'PSY35'
)
```

FacilityListView looks like this:

```
FacilityID  Facilities
SOL1        SOL1,
PSY35       PSY3,PSY5
SOL1W       SOL1,WSR1,
```

I get 0 results since SQL server is looking for a dataset and not an individual value but I don't know how to tell SQL server to select where f.FacilityID in ('PSY3','PSY5')

Comment: Ideally you should be fixing your data here, and not storing delimited data.

Comment: Fix your data.  This will only give you headache in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and use the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Facility.FacilityIO f INNER JOIN FacilityListView v
ON ',' + v.Facilities + ',' LIKE '%,' + f.FacilityID + ',%'
WHERE v.FacilityID = 'PSY35'
```

Comment: I with that would work, but some facilities are PSY1 or PSY10 so that wouldn't work

Comment: Yes this would work because I concatenate commas before and after each value. So this code compares `,PSY1,` or `,PSY10,`

Comment: If Facilities always ends with a comma you can change the ON clause to: `ON ',' + v.Facilities LIKE '%,' + f.FacilityID + ',%'`